# Can we shoot photos with a very shallow DoF with the Lumix FZ300 at any focal length?

Tags: depth-of-field

I couldn't find that information anywhere. Lot says you can't get a shallow DoF with a tiny sensor. So, anyone has got an FZ300, Can you?

mattdm, that question was about all p&s's in common, I posted this question because I saw a video which was shot by this camera, that had a lot of shallow DoF shots. So I need to know if this camera can shoot photos with a shallow DoF *at any focal length*.

Comment: Maybe also see [How does changing focal length affect depth of field?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/37/how-does-changing-focal-length-affect-depth-of-field)

Comment: @dpollitt Maybe he *doesn't* have access to an FZ300 but is asking because he is considering buying one?

Answer (score -1):

Depth of Field or short focus has nothing to do with the cameras sensor. Instead it involves the amount of zoom in pair with the size of the lens opening called apture. The Apture as mentioned in another answer suggest that this camera can open its lens to an apture of 2.8. This is considered to be pretty good for a short focus range in combination with a zoomed in setting and should give you the results you desire.

Comment: Sorry, your answer is only partially correct. Depth of Field has a lot to do with the size of the camera's sensor.  There are 3 things which determine DOF:   1) Sensor Size 2) Aperture 3) Magnification (focal length and subject distance)